# How to generate Pux actions from a foreign module?

Tags: javascript, codemirror, purescript, purescript-pux

I'm trying to write an application using `purescript-pux` and [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/), a static code editor.

CodeMirror makes an editor from a `text-area`, but the events are handled differently, therefore I cannot use the `onChange` function from `Pux.Html.Events`.

To handle input changes in a CodeMirror editor, one should do it this way:

```
CodemirrorInstance.on('change',function(cMirror){
  // get value right from instance
  var newValue = cMirror.getValue();
});
```

I'm able to make a Codemirror instance which is some trivial work. The problem I'm having is about how do I make `pux` aware of the events.

I have a `Channel` which I have subscribed to and I use for handling websocket messages, but I don't really know how could I send something over there from the foreign JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you maybe just need to setup a signal (purescript-signal ) on your foreign module.

Maybe something like this:

```
function CMChangeSignal(constant) {
    /** take initial value here if it  possible and pass it to constan fnt */
    var out = constant();
    // listen to it
    CodemirrorInstance.on('change',function(cMirror){
        // get value right from instance
        var newValue = cMirror.getValue();
        out.set(newValue);
    });
    return function () {
        return out;
    }
}
```

then on your purescript file:

```
// type it, read the CodeMirror Docs.
type CMChange = 
    { from :: CMCoordinate
      to :: CMCoordinate
      text :: Array String
      removed :: String
      origin :: ??
    }

foreign import _CMChangeSignal :: forall eff change. (change -> Signal change) -> Eff (dom :: DOM | eff) (Signal CMChange)

cmChanged :: forall eff. Eff (dom :: DOM | eff) (Signal CMChange)
cmChanged = _CMChangeSignal constant

main :: Eff (CoreEffects (dom :: DOM)) Unit
main = do
  urlSignal <- sampleUrl
  let routeSignal = urlSignal ~> (PageView <<< match)
  -- create signal then map it to your Action
  cmSignal <- cmChanged
  let cmChangeSignal = cmSignal ~> CodeMirrorChangedAction

  app <- start
    { initialState: init
    , update: update
    , view: view
    , inputs: [routeSignal, cmChangeSignal]
    }

  renderToDOM "#app" app.html
```

`constant` is function defined in "purescript-signal" that Pux depend.